# How to rewrite headers in $httpProvider config.headers with new $http request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, xmlhttprequest

In AngularJS I have config for default headers (for Authentification) 
it works fine, every $http request going with right headers.
But for some request I need to change this headers to another values. But I cant! I can only add new one, but can't rewrite previous value.
Thanks!

Here is a thousands  lines of code, so there is most important part of this issue

```
    //THIS PART OF CONFIG
.config(['$locationProvider',
        '$stateProvider',
        '$urlRouterProvider',
        '$httpProvider',
        function ($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider){
            //....
            $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');
        }

// THIS FACTORY
.factory('AuthInterceptor', ['$q',
    function($q) {
        return {
            request: function(config) {
                config.headers = config.headers || {};
                config.headers.Authorization = 'OldValue';
                return config || $q.when(config);
            },
            response: function(response){
                if (response.status === 401) {
                    console.log('Response 401');
                }
                return response || $q.when(response);
            },
            responseError: function(rejection) {
                if (rejection.status === 401) {
                    console.log('Response Error 401',rejection);
                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        };
    }
])

//THIS PART OF CONTROLLER
$scope.makeRequest = function(){
    var request = $http({
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Authorization' : 'NewValue', // do not work
            'NewAuthorisatnion' : 'AnotherValue' // works fine
        url: '/'

    });
    request.
        success(function (data) {
            //...
        });
}
```

Comment: You can override the previous value, show your code.

Comment: could you share the code which you have written

Comment: Thanks. I add some code samples